# Why only pdf cannot be download in Safari

Tags: mobile-safari

I have created a web page which including a download button can let people download pdf, I use below JS code

`var element = (<any>window).document.createElement('a');`
`element.setAttribute('href',dataCtx.getDATA());`
`element.setAttribute('download', dataCtx.getPDF()+"_"+curDate);`
`element.click();`
`element.close();`

it's working fine on Chrome both desktop and mobile, but it's not working on Safari of mobile.
when i change download format to .zip, it's working OK on Safari of mobile.

So why only pdf cannot be download on Safari mobile, what problem would be?

(DATA value is base64 value of pdf url return from backend process)

Answer (score -1):

@Nashearer Can you add below line and check :

```
element.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
```

Comment: Thanks for helping, but i try to add that line, still not working for Safari mobile